# Using _.uniqBy to keep an object that has a larger value of a key in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/fr9qtzm2/13)

```
let obj = [{'vote':999,'name':'D'},
           {'vote':341,'name':'A'},
           {'vote':789,'name':'A'},
           {'vote':555,'name':'B'}]

let result = _.uniqBy(obj,(item)=>{
  return item.name
})
result = _.orderBy(result,(item)=>{
  return item.mid
},['desc'])
```

I want to remove the duplicated By name. In this case I want`{'vote':341,'name':'A'}` removed because it has fewer votes than the other one.
Is there a way to compare the vote values during `_.uniqBy`?

I have also tried running `_.orderBy` first before `_.uniqBy` but there is no guarantee that `{'vote':341,'name':'A'}` is going to be the one removed.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/fr9qtzm2/14/)

I'm using lodash 4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this pure JS approach:

```js
let obj = [{'vote':999,'name':'D'},{'vote':341,'name':'A'},{'vote':789,'name':'A'},{'mid':555,'name':'B'}]
let result = [];
obj.reduce(function(p, c){
  if(p[c.name] === undefined){
    result.push(c);
    p[c.name] = c.vote;
  }
  else if(c.vote > p[c.name]){
    let o = result.find(x=> x.name === c.name);
    o.vote = c.vote
  }
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

---

#### Lodash approach

**Logic**

- Sort array in ascending order by `name` and descending order by `vote`.
- Now use `_.uniqBy` as it will pick first occurrence.

**Note:** I was unable to sort using lodash (`4.17`) (have not used it much), so I have use pure JS to sort it.

**Lodash 4.17**

As correctly pointed by @[Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157454/ori-drori), we should use `_.sortedUniqBy` instead of `_.uniqBy` as it is optimised for sorted arrays.

```js
let obj = [{'vote':999,'name':'D'},{'vote':341,'name':'A'},{'vote':789,'name':'A'},{'mid':555,'name':'B'}]

var sortedArray = obj.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) || b.vote - a.vote
});

var result = _.sortedUniqBy(sortedArray, 'name');
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Lodash 3.10**

```js
let obj = [{'vote':999,'name':'D'},{'vote':341,'name':'A'},{'vote':789,'name':'A'},{'mid':555,'name':'B'}]

var result =_.uniq(
              _.sortByOrder(
                obj, 
                ["name", "vote"], 
                ["asc", "desc"]
              ), "name");
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If the array is sorted, you can use the optimize [`_.sortedUniqBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortedUniqBy).